# The requested URL was not found on this server when clicking button by selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to download files on the website (https://www1.mbrace.or.jp/od2/B/dindex.html). My code successfully worked until the second last line, but the button (input tag actually) cannot be clicked. The code does not occur any errors but it is shown on the website,

'The requested URL was not found on this server'

The URL is perfectly correct, and the input tag is in the second frame tag.

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
url = 'https://www1.mbrace.or.jp/od2/B/dindex.html'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

frame_month = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.XPATH, 
'//frame[@src="dmenu.html" and @name="menu"]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_month)

select = Select(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.NAME, 'MONTH'))))
select.select_by_value('202311')

driver.switch_to.default_content()

frame_day = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.XPATH, 
'//frame[@src="none.html" and @name="JYOU"]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_day)
input_day = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by.NAME, 'MDAY')))

input_day.send_keys('01')
sleep(3)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by.XPATH, '//input[@type="BUTTON" and 
@value="ダウンロード開始"]')))
sleep(10)
button.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

To download all files for 2023/11 you can use this example:

```py
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www1.mbrace.or.jp/od2/B/202311/mday.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

path = soup.select_one("script").text
path = re.search(r'dir="([^"]+)', path).group(1)
file_url = "https://www1.mbrace.or.jp" + path + "{}.lzh"

urls = []
for inp in soup.select('input[type="radio"]'):
    urls.append(file_url.format(inp["value"]))

print("Found these URLs:")
print(*urls, sep="\n")

# download the urls
for u in urls:
    path = u.split("/")[-1]
    with open(path, "wb") as f_out:
        f_out.write(requests.get(u).content)
        print(path, "saved!")
```

Prints:

```
Found these URLs:
https://www1.mbrace.or.jp/od2/B/202311/b231101.lzh
https://www1.mbrace.or.jp/od2/B/202311/b231102.lzh
https://www1.mbrace.or.jp/od2/B/202311/b231103.lzh

...

b231119.lzh saved!
b231120.lzh saved!
b231121.lzh saved!
b231122.lzh saved!
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! 

I didn't know there are URLs when downloading files. Wonderfully helpful!!

Comment: But how did you find the URL?
"https://www1.mbrace.or.jp/od2/B/202311/mday.html"

Comment: @Ten When you go to https://www1.mbrace.or.jp/od2/B/dindex.html and open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and from the dropdown menu select 202311, you should see the URL there.